# Access common powershell cmdlet parameters from c#

Tags: c#, powershell

more specific I want to access the value of the `ErrorAction` parameter from withing the cmdlet.

In powershell everything works as expected

```bsh
function Get-Test {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (

    )
    (Get-Variable|where{$_.Name -eq "ErrorActionPreference"}).Value

}
Get-Test -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

will output `SilentContinue`

However the same call in c# will output `Continue`

```cs
    [CmdletBinding]
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get,"Test")]
    public class MyClass:PSCmdlet{
        protected override void ProcessRecord(){
            base.ProcessRecord();
            WriteObject(((PSVariable) InvokeCommand.InvokeScript($"Get-Variable|where{{$_.Name -eq 'ErrorActionPreference'}}").First().BaseObject).Value);
        }
    }
```

it looks like there is no link between the `ErrorAction` parameter and the `ErrorActionPreference` when `c#`. I say this because if I do

```bsh
$ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue"
Get-Test # c# version
```

will output `SilentlyContinue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, from within (by definition *compiled*) ***cmdlets*** there is ***no need* to determine whether a common parameter was passed or whether its value is implied by a previously set preference variable**:

- **Cmdlets can rely on the infrastructure** provided by their base class to automatically act appropriately on any common-parameter values passed explicitly or implied by preference variables.

  - E.g., a `WriteVerbose()` call implicitly adjusts its output behavior based on whether `-Verbose` was explicitly specified on cmdlet invocation and, in its absence, the value of the `$VerbosePreference` preference variable in the caller's scope.

In ***advanced functions*** - the implemented-in-PowerShell counterparts to compiled cmdlets - **explicitly specified common parameters are automaticaly translated into *function-scoped preference variables***.

- This is an *implementation detail*, however, and, regrettably, one that is [highly problematic](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4568).
- However, when it *does* work as intended - in advanced functions originating in the same scope domain as the caller - the effect is the same as in compiled cmdlets: Calls to cmdlets such as `Write-Verbose` do implicitly pick up both explicitly specified common parameters as well as the caller's preference-variable values (in the latter case via scopes in the same scope domain implicitly seeing variables in the (nearest) ancestral scope).